# Post Request with angular doesn't return anything from my Action Method

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, post

I am using Angular to send POST request to save the object in my DB and it works, but after saving information it doesn't return the `View()` (or Content, string, nothing):

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private MyDb _db = new MyDb();

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Test(SomeModel personalInformation)
    {
        _db.InfoTables.Add(personalInformation);
        _db.SaveChanges();

        // ??
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh..does you views have `test.cshtml` in `Home` folder?

Comment: @PankajParkar As I said, that is not a `View()` problem, I have tried it with different return types; and yes, I have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use return View() if you're doing your POST via ajax/Angular. You'll want to use javascript to manage your ng-view or redirect to a new url on success.

Since this is a normal MVC controller, you can post to it with the [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service, then put your view change code in the success function.

Comment: I am sending requests with `$http`, but I kinda want to do it with Action Methods.

Comment: Then you're doing it with ajax, in which case you can't use actions. You will have to manually handle the data returned by the ajax request.

Comment: Unless you just want to refresh the entire page. Which defeats the purpose of using Angular.